# How to have accessible swipe action for iCarousel

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, icarousel, uiaccessibility

I am trying to make an accessible app. The problem arises when I wanted to have standard ([Three-finger swipe right or left](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityonYourDevicewithVoiceOver/TestAccessibilityonYourDevicewithVoiceOver.html)) behavior with [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel). 
Since iCarousel is not fully accessible by nature and it just lets user to have items be User intractable.

I done some research, there are some workarounds but
I also don't want to implement [UIAccessibilityCustomAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316189/custom-voiceover-actions-in-uitableviewcell#16317800) cause this will not give the user easy to swipe ability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override and implement [accessibilityScroll(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615161-accessibilityscroll)
 method as:

```
extension iCarousel {
    override open func accessibilityScroll(_ direction: UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool {
        super.accessibilityScroll(direction)

        if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.left {
            self.scroll(byOffset: 1, duration: 1.0)
        }
        if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.right {
            self.scroll(byOffset: -1, duration: 1.0)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

and post a desire (e.g. page number) in iCarousel delegate method *carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation*, you may also change the accessibilityLabel and other accessibility related values here.

```
func carouselDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ carousel: iCarousel) {
    self.carousel.accessibilityLabel = accLabels[currentItemIndex]
    self.carousel.accessibilityValue = accValues[currentItemIndex]
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification,
                                    "item \(currentItemIndex + 1) of \(self.items.count)")
}
```

Also in *viewDidLoad* set the initial accessibilityLabel as well as:

```
self.carousel.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitUpdatesFrequently
```

I hope this helps someone.